# The remote server returned an error: (502) Bad Gateway. in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm creating a shopify app using ASP.NET MVC, I made some code changes. 
When I tried to run the application, I got the following error message

> **Error:** **The remote server returned an error: (502) Bad Gateway.**

[image: Screenshot]

I always make backups for my application, because I got the error message, I decided to replace it with my backup file. But the same error still occurs.

I am a beginner both in the shopify app as well as C#. Can anyone explain why this happened and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access an invalid connectionString **shopUrl**. Check this

Answer (score 0):

İt is a proxy problem. Change current proxy to default proxy :
 httpRequest.Proxy = GlobalProxySelection.GetEmptyWebProxy();